# ANTLR4 Parser error for a mini SMTLIB v2 Grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr4, smt

My SMTLib v2 Grammar is as follows :

```
/**
* Author : Sourav DAS
* Group : Rigorous System Design
* Lab : VERIMAG, IMAG Building, UGA
* Date : 23/11/2018
* A Grammar for syntax, defined for test cases, to be run in Parametric Dead-lock Finder
* Inspired from the complete SMTLibV2 grammar present at 
* https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/smtlibv2
**/

grammar SyntaxGrammarSMTLibV2;

Colon
    : ':'
    ;

generalReservedWord
    : GenResWrd_Exclamation
    | GenResWrd_Underscore
    | GenResWrd_As
    | GenResWrd_Exists
    | GenResWrd_Forall
    | GenResWrd_Numeral
    | GenResWrd_String
    ;

fragment Digit
    : [0-9]
    ;

fragment Sym
    : 'a'..'z'
    | 'A' .. 'Z'
    | '+'
    | '='
    | '/'
    | '*'
    | '%'
    | '?'
    | '!'
    | '$'
    | '-'
    | '_'
    | '~'
    | '&'
    | '^'
    | '<'
    | '>'
    | '@'
    | '.'
    ;

fragment PrintCharNoDQuote
    : '\u0020' .. '\u0021'
    | '\u0023' .. '\u007E'
    | '\u0080' .. '\uffff'
    | EscapedSpace
    ;

Numeral
    : '0'
    | [1-9] Digit*
    ;

UndefinedSymbol:
    Sym (Digit | Sym)*
    ;

QuotedSymbol:
    '|' (PrintableCharNoBackslash | WhiteSpaceChar)+ '|'
    ;

simpleSymbol
    : UndefinedSymbol
    ;

quotedSymbol
    : QuotedSymbol
    ;

symbol
    : simpleSymbol
    | quotedSymbol
    ;

index
    : Numeral
    | symbol
    ;

ParenthesisOpen
    : '('
    ;

ParenthesisClose
    : ')'
    ;

identifier
    : symbol
    | ParenthesisOpen GenResWrd_Underscore symbol index+ ParenthesisClose
    ;

sort_expr
    : symbol
    | ParenthesisOpen symbol sort_expr+ ParenthesisClose
    ;

// Command names    

CMD_DeclareFun
    : 'declare-fun'
    ;

CMD_DeclareSort
    : 'declare-sort'
    ;

CMD_DefineFun
    : 'define-fun'
    ;

CMD_DefineSort
    : 'define-sort'
    ;

cmd_declareFun
    : CMD_DeclareFun
    ;

cmd_declareSort
    : CMD_DeclareSort
    ;

cmd_defineSort
    : CMD_DefineSort
    ;

cmd_defineFun
    : CMD_DefineFun
    ;

// General reserved words

GenResWrd_Exclamation
    : '!'
    ;

GenResWrd_Underscore
    : '_'
    ;

GenResWrd_As
    : 'as'
    ;

GenResWrd_Numeral
    : 'Numeral'
    ;

GenResWrd_String
    : 'string'
    ;

GenResWrd_Exists
    : 'exists'
    ;

GenResWrd_Forall
    : 'forall'
    ;

fragment EscapedSpace
    : '""'
    ;

fragment PrintableCharNoBackslash
    : '\u0020' .. '\u005B'
    | '\u005D' .. '\u007B'
    | '\u007D' .. '\u007E'
    | '\u0080' .. '\uffff'
    | EscapedSpace
    ;

fragment WhiteSpaceChar
    : '\u0009'
    | '\u000A'
    | '\u000D'
    | '\u0020'
    ;

// Sorts

sort
    : identifier
    | ParenthesisOpen identifier sort+ ParenthesisClose
    ;

sorted_var
    : ParenthesisOpen symbol sort ParenthesisClose
    ;

qualified_identifier
    : identifier
    | ParenthesisOpen GenResWrd_As identifier sort ParenthesisClose
    ;

String
    : '"' (PrintCharNoDQuote | WhiteSpaceChar)+ '"'
    ;

string
    : String
    ;

spec_constant
    : Numeral
    | string
    ;

function_dec
    : ParenthesisOpen symbol ParenthesisOpen sort_expr* ParenthesisClose sort_expr ParenthesisClose
    ;

function_def
    : symbol ParenthesisOpen ParenthesisOpen symbol sort_expr ParenthesisClose* ParenthesisClose sort_expr expr
    ;

s_expr
    : spec_constant
    | symbol
    | keyword
    | ParenthesisOpen s_expr* ParenthesisClose
    ;

keyword
    : Colon simpleSymbol
    ;

// Attributes

attribute_value
    : spec_constant
    | symbol
    | ParenthesisOpen s_expr* ParenthesisClose
    ;

attribute
    : keyword
    | keyword attribute_value
    ;

attributed_expr
    : ParenthesisOpen GenResWrd_Exclamation expr attribute+ ParenthesisClose 
    ;

expr
    : spec_constant
    | identifier
    | qualified_identifier
    | ParenthesisOpen qualified_identifier expr+ ParenthesisClose
    | ParenthesisOpen GenResWrd_Forall ParenthesisOpen ParenthesisOpen symbol sort ParenthesisClose+ ParenthesisClose expr ParenthesisClose
    | ParenthesisOpen GenResWrd_Exists ParenthesisOpen ParenthesisOpen symbol sort ParenthesisClose+ ParenthesisClose expr ParenthesisClose
    | ParenthesisOpen GenResWrd_Exclamation expr attribute+ ParenthesisClose
    ;

model_response
    : ParenthesisOpen CMD_DefineFun function_def ParenthesisClose
    // cardinalities for function_dec and expr have to be n+1
    ParenthesisClose ParenthesisClose
    ;

command
    : ParenthesisOpen cmd_declareFun symbol ParenthesisOpen sort* ParenthesisClose sort ParenthesisClose
    | ParenthesisOpen cmd_declareSort symbol Numeral ParenthesisClose
    | ParenthesisOpen cmd_defineFun function_def ParenthesisClose
    | ParenthesisOpen cmd_defineSort symbol ParenthesisOpen symbol* ParenthesisClose sort ParenthesisClose
    ;

// Parser Rules End

WS  :  [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
    ;
```

And my testcase is :

```
(declare-fun s0 (Int ) Bool)
(declare-fun s1 (Int ) Bool)
(declare-fun s2 (Int ) Bool)
(declare-fun s3 (Int ) Bool)
(declare-fun s4 (Int ) Bool)
(implies (forall ((i Int)) (and (>= i 0) (<= i 3))) (and (implies (and (s4 i) (s0 (% (+ i 1) 4)) (and (s0 i) (s1 (% (+ i 1) 4)))) (implies (s1 i) (s2 i)) (implies (s1 i) (s4 i)) (implies (s3 i) (s4 i)) (implies (s2 i) (s3 i)))))
```

When I run it with grun, I get the following error :

```
> grun SyntaxGrammarSMTLibV2 expr Examples/example6_Mutual_Exclusion_Protocol.smt2 -gui
line 1:21 extraneous input ')' expecting {Numeral, UndefinedSymbol, QuotedSymbol, '(', String}
line 2:21 extraneous input ')' expecting {Numeral, UndefinedSymbol, QuotedSymbol, '(', String}
line 3:21 extraneous input ')' expecting {Numeral, UndefinedSymbol, QuotedSymbol, '(', String}
line 4:21 extraneous input ')' expecting {Numeral, UndefinedSymbol, QuotedSymbol, '(', String}
line 5:21 extraneous input ')' expecting {Numeral, UndefinedSymbol, QuotedSymbol, '(', String}
line 6:19 no viable alternative at input '(i'
line 7:0 extraneous input '<EOF>' expecting {Numeral, UndefinedSymbol, QuotedSymbol, '(', ')', String}
```

Can anybody help me figure out the defects in my grammar?

Answer (score 0):

Your `expr` rule is defined to match a single expression. But the input you feed it is a list of commands, followed by an expression. You should either feed it a single expression instead or define a rule that matches a list of commands and expressions and use that rule instead of `expr`.

Also note that `declare-fun` is interpreted as `UndefinedSymbol`s rather than `CMD_DeclareFun` because `UndefinedSymbol` comes first in the grammar and thus takes precedent. Otherwise you'd already get an error at the beginning of the line, telling you that `declare-fun` isn't expected at the beginning of an expression.

It's also why using `forall` or `exists` isn't going to work because it isn't going to recognize `forall` or `exists` as reserved words.

To fix both of those issues, move the definition of `UndefinedSymbol` to the end of your token definitions (which, from a readability standpoint, should be all in one place, not intermixed with parser rules).